# Using Array.BinarySearch() to return first value <= lookup value?

Tags: c#, arrays, lookup, where-clause, binary-search

I'm trying to create a "lookup" column that would return the index of the array value that is equal to or **less than** the value being looked up. So this is my attempt, which seems to work fine, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing it ?

```
// Sorted
float[] ranges = new float[]
  {
     0.8f,
     1.1f,
     2.7f,
     3.9f,
     4.5f,
     5.1f,
  };


private int GetIndex(float lookupValue)
{
    int position = Array.BinarySearch(ranges, lookupValue);
    if (position < 0)
    {
        // Find the highest available value that does not
        // exceed the value being looked up.
        position = ~position - 1;
    }

    // If position is still negative => all values in array 
    // are greater than lookupValue, return 0
    return position < 0 ? 0 : position;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: BinarySearch is fast and I think it's pretty clean what you have.

Comment: **Define *'cleaner'*.** The code works. It's concise. Well commented. What more are you looking for?

Comment: Although the solution above DOES assume the input array is sorted...

Comment: Cleaner from my preferences would mean removing the wordy comments, but that's a preference. I wouldn't touch the code.. I think you have the best solution.

Comment: Perhaps using Array.BinarySearch Method (Array, Object, IComparer) instead ?

Comment: May I ask what the "~" does in the Array.BinarySearch() statement? I have a feeling it has something to do with garbage collection but i'm merely guessing.

Comment: @Jamie Keeling - the `~` is the bitwise complement operator; it's used in this case because `Array.BinarySearch` returns the complement of the index of the next higher element, if it can't find the item you're looking for.

Comment: @alhazen - note that returning a 0 if everything is greater than your lookup value might not be the best idea; it becomes ambiguous whether 0 means "the first element is smaller" **or**  "nothing is smaller". You might want to return -1 in the latter case; simplifies your code too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, I think this is a pretty good approach.

The only thing I might change is to make it an extension method on arrays, instead of a private function referring to a class variable. Then it becomes general / not tied to one class, and the syntax is cleaner too: `ranges.GetIndex(...)`

Something like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int GetIndex<T>(this T[] ranges, T lookupValue)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll have to remember this only works on sorted arrays...

Comment: +1 because extensions are nice, though I would maybe constrain the types so you don't have intellisense popping this GetIndex on an array of some complex data type..

Answer (score 1):

You could use a normal for loop (assuming your data is ordered). Not sure if it's cleaner, but certainly not as effective on lots of data. Personally I would go for the BinarySearch you have.

```
int GetIndex(IList<float> ranges, float target)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Count; i++)
    {
        if(ranges[i] < target) continue;
        if (ranges[i] >= target) return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```